# How to gain access to SF1 Platform App builder and Process builder?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-platform, dreamforce, process-builder

I've seen the recent videos of Dreamforce about the new Lightning and other SF1 platform products. Can someone guide me to get the access to the Lightning App builder and the Inspection/process builder? Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce1 lightning components is still in beta but are available in newer orgs. Spin up a new DE org and enable lightning under setup.

You would have to get in touch with salesforce to enable app builder since it is still in development.

Process builder can also be enabled by getting in touch with your ae and/or support.

Comment: No worries! Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

The Lightning App Builder is available as a Pilot in Spring '15. To gain access to the pilot, contact your Account Exec and request to be nominated.

Answer (score 1):

The **Lightning Process Builder** Beta is available now in all EE, UE and Performance Editions by logging a case with Support via the Help link in your org. You can find the Guide here: https://success.salesforce.com/06930000003qh7I
Also check out the Success Community of Beta users: [Official: Salesforce Workflow Automation](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000001rzcCAA)